# Why $().load() works but $.ajax() doesn't work in a phonegap app?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have following piece of code which tries to load an XML file from web.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.kumarchetan.com/blog/feed/',
    success: function(xhrresponse){
        $('#container').html(xhrresponse);//does nothing
        navigator.notification.alert("Data Loaded: " + typeof xhrresponse);//tells me its an object
    },
    error: function(){
        navigator.notification.alert("PC LOAD LETTER");
    }
});
```

I tried using `$.get()` as well but it didnt work. I replaced this code with following

```
$('#hiddenContainer').load('http://www.kumarchetan.com/blog/feed/');
```

And it works like charm. The server that hosts XML files doesn't have anything special done at server side.

**EDIT**
I tried adding `dataType:'xml'` as well, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you developing the App for iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised that I had to add a timeout of 5 seconds before I start using the XML response.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly setting the data type? Like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.kumarchetan.com/blog/feed/',
    success: function(xhrresponse){
        $('#container').html(xhrresponse);//does nothing
        navigator.notification.alert("Data Loaded: " + typeof xhrresponse);//tells me its an object
    },
    error: function(){
        navigator.notification.alert("PC LOAD LETTER");
    },
    dataType: 'xml'
});
```

Or

```
$.get('http://www.kumarchetan.com/blog/feed/', function(xhrresponse){
    $('#container').html(xhrresponse);//does nothing
    navigator.notification.alert("Data Loaded: " + typeof xhrresponse);//tells me its an object
}, 'xml');
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did add the `dataType` parameter as well but it didn't work, I will update the question.